# MySQL view using PFK

Tags: mysql, view

I have this tables:

```
Create table table1 (
 id Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, 
 Primary Key(id),
 Unique Key `name` (`name`)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Create table table2 (
 id1 Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 id2 Int UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
 Primary Key (id1,id2)) 
ENGINE = InnoDB;

Alter table table2 add Foreign Key (id1) references table1 (id) 
on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
Alter table table2 add Foreign Key (id2) references table1 (id) 
on delete  restrict on update  restrict;
```

I would like to ask, is there any possibility how to create a type of `view`, which would contain names of both users (from `table1`) which are mentioned in `table2`? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW ViewName
AS
SELECT
    T1.Name Name1, T2.Name Name2
FROM Table2 T
    JOIN Table1 T1
        ON T.Id1 = T1.Id
    JOIN Table1 T2
        ON T.Id2 = T2.Id;
```

Answer (score 0):

This will put all names in the view whose ids are present in Table2 in both columns.

```
CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Table1 
WHERE Id IN (SELECT DISTINCT Id1 FROM Table2 
UNION SELECT DISTINCT Id2 FROM Table2)
```